# How to restore file.lib to default (Labview)

Tags: labview

I overwrote by mistake some Labview 8.6 VIs from file.lib. Is the any way to restore to default? If not, Can anyone send my a copy of this library. All my projects does not work!! It is so import.
Thanks

Comment: Try to open the original installer using 7zip. There it should be somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Just reinstall LabVIEW. It will restore all core libraries to a good state.

Answer (score 0):

Try repairing the Labview Installation.

Before starting the repairing, rename the folder: the installer should then be forced to regenerate the folder with the default files.